# Installing Docker through apt vs snap?

Tags: apt, snap, docker

I'm starting to build my own media server which will use Docker for different packages. Mainly Plex, Radarr, and so on.

Although I've dabbled a bit with Linux before, I was never aware of what `snap` is, always used `apt`.

Now that I started reading on it, I can see the appeal for certain usages, mainly for testing and self contained programs such as GIMP.

However, I'm confused with Docker, since it connects its own containers to other containers and then to the system. Would that mean the Docker container are within the `snap` container, if I installed it through `snap`?

Are there any noticeable differences between `snap` and `apt` for Docker specifically? Any functional difference? Any usage difference that I might end up hitting a while later down the road?

I.e if I were to receive a computer with Docker installed with either one, would my usage differ from one to other or is it all the same?

I read that some people said `snap` boots slower sometimes, but other than that, is there a difference?

Comment: "*Are there any noticeable differences between snap and apt for docker specifically?*" Not really, since it seems like you won't be interacting with apt or snap after installing docker. Use whichever you feel more comfortable using.

Comment: "*Would that mean the docker container are within the snap container, if I installed it through snap?*" Snaps are not *containers*. Snaps are *software packages*. While Snaps use sandboxing, they do not use containerization to do that sandboxing. So "yes" in the sense that yes-you-are nesting sandboxes, and "no" in the sense that no-you-are-not nesting containers.

Answer (score 14):

In my experience and opinion, there will not be much difference in using Docker from `snap` vs. `apt` installation. It is however important, that you choose one ***or*** the other, as they can't really co-exist. As for addressing some of your specific question:

*Would that mean the docker container are within the snap container, if I installed it through snap?*

In a way this is true. But rather, the Docker containers run in an isolated environment. However, the `snap` abstraction is rather transparent, so I don't believe there is any practical difference in performance.

*Are there any noticeable differences between snap and apt for docker specifically? Any functional difference? Any usage difference that I might end up hitting a while later down the road?*

The biggest difference might be in the containment of the data. From the Snapcraft Docker page:

> This build can only access files in the home directory. So Dockerfiles and all other files used in commands like docker build, docker save and docker load need to be in $HOME.

So by default, the `snap` version will only access files in `$HOME`, while the `apt` version can access files anywhere.

As you also mentioned, `snaps` can affect booting and loading times - but mostly on older systems. On newer systems with SSD disks, this shouldn't be an issue.

In addition, when running the `snap` version, the Docker service running (`docker.service`) isn't directly visible on the system. This means that any fine-tuning of the systemd service isn't possible to the same extent as with the `apt` version.

Finally, `snap` applications update automatically, with a fallback option to the last 2 versions by default. You may or may not prefer this.

As of 2022/03/31 and for Ubuntu 20.04 Focal, the [`apt` version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/docker.io) of Docker is 20.10.7, while the [`snap` version](https://snapcraft.io/docker) is 20.10.12.

For reference, the latest version from the official Docker repos is 20.10.14. So if you want the absolute latest release, it is advised to install as an `apt` package from the [official Docker repos](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

##### Conclusion

Overall, the basic functionality of Docker will be the same (setting aside data containment, service control and possible minor version differences), no matter which installation option you choose. Both the `snap` and `apt` version should generally be suitable for production use, but the `apt` version will allow more possibilities for low-level control and customization.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have some issues with installing docker via apt because of the firewall so I tried snap and I noticed one more difference, the snap installation is missing the `docker.service`: `$sudo systemctl status docker.service #Unit docker.service could not be found.` I agree that for basic usecases snap can do the job but I think for heavy usecases snap is very limiting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I'll include this in my answer. I suspect that the `docker.service` is part of the snap that's running, so you also loose some of that granular service control with the snap version.

Comment: I am getting lots of networking errors with the snap version, so completely similar they are not.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against the usage of `snap` version of `docker`, as well as any other `snap` package if you already using the `apt` packages in the system. Generally, it is considered a bad practice to use several different package managers in the system, and if you use Ubuntu (not Ubuntu Core) - you already use `apt` packages, so using `snap` for anything should be done with caution.

For example, if you install `docker` via `snap` (possibly via installation of some other `snap` package which depends on `docker`, like the `dive` tool which is absent from apt repositories, but is available via `snap`), it would silently break your existing apt `docker` installation - snap would silently overwrite `/var/run/docker.sock`, and your currently running `docker` containers would become unavailable. You would need to remove `snap`'s `docker`, and use `systemctl restart docker.socket` to fix.